# How to declare a instance name for different classes in Swift

Tags: swift

I have two classes which have the same variables and the same methods but the methods do different things. I want to declare an instance name and later on I want to decide which of the classes will be instanciated.

```
class A {
   var x : Int = 0

   func calc() {
       x = 10     
   }
}

class B {
   var x : Int = 0

   func calc() {
       x = 33     
   }
}

class X : UIViewController {
   var value : Int = 0
   var AorB : (class A or B, I decide later on in the code)

   ...

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // Here I want to decide that aorB is an Instance of A or of B

}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: It's helpful if you show what you tried doing, including any errors and if you searched for any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
    protocol SomeProtocol{}

    class A:SomeProtocol {
           var x : Int = 0

           func calc() {
               x = 10     
           }
    }

    class B:SomeProtocol {
           var x : Int = 0

           func calc() {
               x = 33     
           }
    }

    class X : UIViewController {
           var value : Int = 0

           var AorB : SomeProtocol!

           ...

           override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()

              AorB = A()
              AorB = B()

              // Here I want to decide that aorB is an Instance of A or of B

  }
```

Comment: Ok. At least I decided to put all functions in one class. Works fine.